# data type for date with different format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to import a .csv file to SQL through SQL commands. In a .csv file, a date is there but the format MM-DD-YY & MM-DD-YYY while creating table what data type I have to use. I use the date as a data type . while loading the file it's not accepting the date.

Comment: If you have tried some code then post it here otherwise question will be downvoted!

Comment: You're allowed to use google before posting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SET` clause:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE t(@var)
  SET datecol = (CASE WHEN LENGTH(@var) = 8 THEN str_to_date(@var, '%m-%d-%y')
                      WHEN LENGTH(@var) = 10 THEN str_to_date(@var, '%m-%d-%Y')
                 END);
```

Personally, though, I would load the data into a staging table where all the columns are strings.  Then I would do the conversion(s) using SQL code on that table.  That is easier to debug and to find all the problems (as well as looking up foreign key ids).

Comment: create table sports ( Name varchar(30), Age int, Country Varchar(30), Yearofsports year, Dateofsports date, sportstype Varchar(30), Gold int, Silver int, Bronze int, Total int); in this date datatype is not working while importing data its showing 0000-00-00 which datatype i have to use .